# Returning vector's pointer in c++ doesn't work

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I am testing some pointers in c++. My code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector <int>& vec_return(){
    vector<int> test_vec;
    test_vec.push_back(1);
    test_vec.push_back(2);
    test_vec.push_back(3);
    test_vec.push_back(4);
    test_vec.push_back(5);

    return test_vec;
}

int main(){
    vector <int>& test_vec = vec_return();
    for(int i = 0; i < test_vec.size(); i++){
        cout<<test_vec[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am  thinking the vec_return() function should return the pointer of a test_vec and then in main it should be printed but instead it doesn't do anything. Any suggestions?

Comment: test_vec is defined in the scope of the function. You are returning a reference to an object that goes immediately out of scope after the return. This gives undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning references to stack variables is undefined behaviour: you create a variable in `vec_return`, it gets destroyed before exiting from this function, but you still keep a reference to it in `main`. Change signature of `vec_return()` to be `vector<int> vec_return()`, so that compiler can perform [copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) and make sure that the object is constructed only once.

Also, it's better to call `test_vec.reserve(N);` in `vec_return` before pushing anything into it to pre-allocate memory, where `N` is the expected number of calls to `push_back`, or (since C++11) initialise it directly like this: `vector<int> test_vec{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`.

Comment: Ok, but then in the main if I write vector<int>& test_vec = vec_return(). It gives the error. and If i ignore the ampersand It will create new vector, and I don't want it. what to do?

Comment: The compiler will use [return value optimisation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) and the object will be constructed only once.

Answer (score 0):

This function returns *reference* to temporary object

```
vector <int>& vec_return(){
```

so using result of this function in the `main()` is undefined behavior.

Comment: Ok, but then in the main if I write vector<int>& test_vec = vec_return(). It gives the error. and If i ignore the ampersand It will create new vector, and I don't want it. what to do?

Comment: Pass reference to empty vector into the `void vec_return(vector <int>&) ` and fill it in the function.

Comment: The better option is to return by value. In this case RVO will probably (until C++17) / definitely (since C++17) make the object to be constructed only once.

Comment: @DevNull any *real* compiler that does that? I didn't found any, between Intel , MS and PGI, copy constructors are called, in case of GCC - move one.

Comment: @Swift at least gcc >= 4.9.2 and clang >= 3.6.1 do it [*live example*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3977e69edb60078d).

Answer (score 0):

#### With power comes responsibility...

Returning a reference to a local variable results in a dangling reference, *i.e.*, a reference to unallocated data, which is UB.

```
std::vector<int>& vec_return() {
    std::vector<int> test_vec; // Create local object.

    /* ... */

    return test_vec; // Return reference to local object.
} // Here all local objects are destroyed.
```

Instead, **return by value**. Any decent compiler will elide (optimize away) the copy. Since C++11, the standard even guarantees a move construction at the call site if no optimizations are available<sup>†</sup>.

```
std::vector<int> vec_return() {
    return {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
}
```

<sub>**†** The C++17 standard (finalized but not ISO published) even *guarantees* the NRVO optimization.</sub>

Comment: Ok, but then in the main if I write vector<int>& test_vec = vec_return(). It gives the error. and If i ignore the ampersand It will create new vector, and I don't want it. what to do?

Comment: @Banned No, you will _not_ create a new `std::vector` when you remove the ampersand. The compiler will optimize it away (even when looking at the code, it may look like a copy is being made)!

Comment: @Banned Look at [this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d0384fc4e50b0bea) where a local object is returned by value while optimizations are turned on.